# When is a cookie available?

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript

Hi i have a web application where i plant a cookie on my page. Then the user goes to another page, and from that page calls my page from a script, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/page.aspx?id=6" ></script>
```

But i cant access the cookie when it calls my page, why not? and how to work around it?

Please note that this question is in relation to: 
[Javascript and webshop tracking/affiliate across websites, how to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660427/javascript-and-webshop-tracking-affiliate-across-websites-how-to-do)

**Edit**
The "other" page is on a entirely different domain. My code is in ASP.NET, but as far as i know its the same for all languages:

Planting the cookie (Default.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["affiliate"].Value = "InnovationPartner";
        Response.Cookies["affiliate"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        ...
    }
```

Retrieving the cookie (after round-trip) (Collect.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool affiliate = Request.Cookies["affiliate"] != null ? true : false;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You need to be far more specific. What "page" do you mean? What "another page"? Is it same domain or different? Where is the reproduce code?

Comment: Please see my edit, hopefully thats explains it a bit more detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers have options to place limitations on ‘third party cookies’, which is what your cookies are for a request caused by a `<script>` tag on another site.

In particular for IE's default settings, you will need to provide a P3P policy. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: ...but i set my cookie on:
http://www.mycomain.com/default.aspx
-> user clicks a link and is redirected to another page (the webshop)
-> When the user has completed order i link back to my domain(the javascript):
http://www.mydomain.Collect.aspx

And its on mydomain.com i am setting and retrieving cookies, nowhere else. But when i try to retrieve my cookie its not there (return null)

Comment: ..what i mean is that, its not a real third pary cookie, when its not used on the domain of the webshop?

Comment: It's a third-party cookie when a resource (script, style, image, iframe) is being fetched from a web page at a hostname that does not match the hostname of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

when called from the different domain, a [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) signature must be implemented.
Anyway, you must always watch an HTTP log to track the cookies flow